# How to select all options in a list with IONIC ion-select

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, frontend

I want a select where I can choice "select All" or "unselect all" options of a list.

I have this in my html:

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label class="opciones">Mas opciones:</ion-label>
      <ion-select class="seleccion" multiple="false" placeholder="Marcar todo">
        <ion-option (click)="selectAll(elemento)">Marcar todo</ion-option>
        <ion-option (click)="unselectAll(elemento)">Desmarcar todo</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

And here is my function

```
elemento = document.getElementsByClassName("anim-icons");
  public selectAll(listaProducto: ListaProducto) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.elemento.length; i++) {
      this.elemento[i].className += " active" + " alt";
      console.log("elemento: " + this.elemento);
    }
  }
```

The css class "active" put the checkbox of a item in check.
My funtion doesn´t work and I'm new with this framework.

Thank you!